# Are There Any Customizable Working Memory Tests?

Tags: memory, working-memory

I've found many working memory tests online, but they all use either the digits 0-9, or the alphabet. Is there a working memory test that lets one choose the characters?

Ex.:
If I input the characters: 0 1 2 3
then the test will output random sequences only containing those 4 characters.

Comment: you could try PEBL, not sure tho